# Parse a array of string objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, object

Based on the JSON data format below, how can we parse it where in I only wanted to get certain key for example I just wanted to get name and priority

```
[  
   "{'id': 12, 'category_name': 'BIR', 'priority': 1, 'category': 12, 'name': 'BIR FORMS'}",
   "{'id': 14, 'category_name': 'Contribution', 'priority': 0, 'category': 13, 'name': 'Pag-Ibig'}",
   "{'id': 13, 'category_name': 'Contribution', 'priority': 0, 'category': 13, 'name': 'SSS'}"
]
```

Comment: you have no parsable [JSON](https://json.org/) in your data, because of the single quotes inside.

Comment: Please show any code that attempts to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no other quotes inside your data, you could replace single quotes `'` with double quotes `"` to get a [JSON](https://json.org/) compliant string.

Then parse the string, get the wanted properties and map new objects.

```js
var strings = [  
        "{'id': 12, 'category_name': 'BIR', 'priority': 1, 'category': 12, 'name': 'BIR FORMS'}",
        "{'id': 14, 'category_name': 'Contribution', 'priority': 0, 'category': 13, 'name': 'Pag-Ibig'}",
        "{'id': 13, 'category_name': 'Contribution', 'priority': 0, 'category': 13, 'name': 'SSS'}"
    ],
    data = strings.map(s => JSON.parse(s.replace(/'/g, '"'))),
    selected = data.map(({ name, priority }) => ({ name, priority }));

console.log(selected);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume that you have valid json data. You can do the following example:

```
const json = `[
   {"priority": 1, "name": "BIR FORMS"},
   {"priority": 0, "name": "Pag-Ibig"},
   {"priority": 0, "name": "SSS"}
]`;
const parsedJson = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(`${parsedJson[0].name}, ${parsedJson[0].priority}`);
```

Answer (score -2):

try to map the data as bellow,

```
 let data=[
"{'id': 12, 'category_name': 'BIR', 'priority': 1, 'category': 12, 'name': 
'BIR FORMS'}", "{'id': 14, 'category_name': 'Contribution', 'priority': 0, 
'category': 13, 'name': 'Pag-Ibig'}", "{'id': 13, 'category_name': 
'Contribution', 'priority': 0, 'category': 13, 'name': 'SSS'}" ];
let mapping= data.map((tmp)=>{
   tmp=JSON.parse(tmp)
   return {name:tmp.name,priority:tmp.priority}
})
```